# Question about using an automator to apply pixelmator watermark

Tags: automator, pixelmator

I have a 13in Mac Book Pro High Sierra and just purchased 3.7 Pixelmator. I am making an automator to place a watermark in bulk of photos and no matter the size of the watermark text, it comes out small after applying the automator, how can I get it to keep the size I created the text in Pixelmator? I just created a simple watermark with a text layer on top of a transparent background saved as a png file.

Comment: Tried - http://www.pixelmatortemplates.com/pixelmator-tip-54-how-to-quickly-add-watermarks-to-your-images/ ?

Comment: Yes, that's what enabled me to make the automator, and it worked just fine, it's just that when the watermark is added to the photo, the font size is very small, and not equivalent to the size of the font in the png I indicate to be used.

Comment: Did you try saving the png at a higher resolution? I can't read all of that workflow, btw, it wants me to sign up to read it.

Comment: It's saved at 300 psi, should it be higher? I didn't try that.

Comment: Assuming you mean dpi, images don’t have a dpi until you print them, all they have are dimensions in pixels.

Comment: I meant pixels per inch; I had tried making it higher, but it didn't change anything

Comment: It wouldn’t. You need to increase the actual *dimensions* not the dpi.

Comment: Ok, yes, I did that as well, which is why I'm confused why it won't change on the watermark applied.

Comment: I think this is going to be something you need you ask Pixelmator about.